# IndexOf fails when there is a backslash in the string -- Why?

Tags: c#, string

Why does IndexOf fail when there is a backslash "\" in the string?

```
string tmpString = "acg2xs5d.dui";

string tmpString2 = @"c:\acg2xs5d.dui"; 

MessageBox.Show(tmpString.IndexOf(@tmpString2).ToString());
```

This returns -1; no matter what.

If I change tmpString2 to "acg2xs5d.dui" and remove the "c:\" it returns 0 as expected.

It seems that the "\" is causing it to give an incorrect result of "-1".

Why is this and how do I work around/trap for this?

Comment: because backslash is an escape character! You have to put it in twice in your string

Comment: Because "\a" is not the same as "a".

Comment: My tmpString2 is always going to contain a filename with a directory path in front of it.  What is the easiest way to change the single backslashes in the directory path to double backslashes?

Comment: Specifically, `\a` is the `bel` control character.

Comment: To code a literal backslash use the doubled backslash -- \\.

Comment: @Hot Licks: But `"\a"` is not the same as `@"\a"`. Notice he is assigning a verbatim string to `tmpString2` - the backslash won't create an escape sequence in this case.

Comment: Since I am assigning a verbatim string, who does it still have the result of -1?

Comment: You trying to find c:\acg2xs5d.dui in acg2xs5d.dui MessageBox.Show(tmpString2.IndexOf(@tmpString).ToString());
the same code works fine in my place

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you need just to use 
`tmpString2.IndexOf(@tmpString)`

instead of 
`tmpString.IndexOf(@tmpString2)`

all is right except of the order. "\" is not an escape character because you use "@" before your string.

Comment: Well spotted :) `IndexOf()` takes as a parameter the substring to search for, not the original string to search in...

Comment: @BoltClock it's like a misprint - very common mistake:)

Comment: +5 for letting the commenters know that '\' doesn't need to be escapted due to the use of '@'.

Answer (score -2):

Include one more slash in the string before searching. Use the below code:

```
string tmpString = "acg2xs5d.dui"; 
string tmpString2 = "c:\\acg2xs5d.dui";
int a = tmpString2.IndexOf(tmpString); //returns 3
```

Comment: Can you elobrate your comment please?

Comment: There are no special characters to normalize here so it's not necessary.

Comment: @Umesh IndexOf() works right without normalization. thus normalization is not necessary.

Comment: again... there is not any difference between "c:\\acg2xs5d.dui" and @"c:\acg2xs5d.dui". the mistake is just in order of strings. so your answer is wrong.